# How to find file using pattern match on AIX?

Tags: linux, find, ksh

I have a list of files as mentioned below on AIX

```
list_aa.cfg
list_bb.cfg
list_cc.cfg
list_dd.cfg
```

I want to search the files as mentioned below

```
find . -name "list_[aa|bb|cc]*.cfg" -ls
```

It did not work on AIX.  Is there any way to accomplish that using command 'find' ?

Comment: try this: **ls list_[aa|bb|cc]*.cfg**

Comment: I tried and It did not work.  I even tried 'ls list_[aa\|bb\|cc]*.cfg' no change in output

Comment: Your shell will expand the asterisk in that because you put the pattern in double quotes (assuming you're on ksh). Does it work with single quotes around the pattern?

Comment: @Bandrami  I am on ksh and I tried    find . -name 'list_[aa|bb]*.cfg'  (using single quotes) but no change in output

Comment: So, fault isolation: what happens with `find . -name 'list*'` ?

Comment: @Bandrami It works.  But I want to pick few out of several 'list_*.cfg' to avoid code redundancy

Comment: I found this 'find . -name 'list*.cfg' | grep 'aa\|bb' and it worked. But not so convincing to me

Comment: Works in bash: `ls -1 list_{aa,bb,cc}*.cfg`

Comment: `[aa|bb|cc]` is mis-use of character classes, which is really functioning as `[abc|]`. Ksh also supports `{aa,bb,cc}` wild carding with the correct env vars turned on (something about csh compatible), but oops, you're using AIX, so likely.not available on your version. Same for wild-cards like `list_*(aa|bb|cc).cfg` (parens). Only available in `ksh93` on AIX (or at least per my experience 5 yrs ago). This is to say that aix has 2 versions of  `ksh` on aix: /bin/ksh is version 88M, and `ksh93` (not sure about paths, might be /usr/bin/). has many more features  . good luck.

Comment: Also, don't forget about single char wild-cards, `list_??.cfg`